# Rails Joins Select Associated Columns not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application there,

AnalyticsPage has the below relations. Many to Many relations with the users.

```
class AnalyticsPage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :graph_page_layout
  has_many :analytics_pages_users
  has_many :users, through: :analytics_pages_users
  has_many :graph_sections
end

##### query #####
I need to write query where I need to fetch the columns from both of the tables.
analytics_pages = AnalyticsPage.select('users.first_name, users.last_name, analytics_pages.title').joins([:users])
```

The above query is not giving users first name and last name.The other point is that when I am running the SQL query it is running in mysql admin.

Answer (score 0):

try with [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

`Pod.pluck('users.first_name, users.last_name').joins(:users)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
analytics_pages = AnalyticsPage.joins(:users).pluck('users.first_name,users.last_name')
```

Alternately if the fields `first_name` and `last_name` are unambiguous, i.e. there exist no fields by the same name in AnalyticsPage model, then the following should also work

```
analytics_pages = AnalyticsPage.joins(:users).pluck([:first_name, :last_name])
```

**Edit 1:**

If you also need to fetch data from AnalyticsPages model as well, here is the way to go

```
analytics_pages = AnalyticsPage.joins(:users).pluck('users.first_name,users.last_name, analytics_pages.field1,analytics_pages.field2')
```

again if the fields are unambiguous the following should work

```
AnalyticsPage.joins(:users).pluck(:user_field_1, :analytics_pages_field_1)
```

The key is to think of ModelA.joins(:model_b) as a single table. in this table, the unambiguous fields are names as they were in original tables, and the ambiguous fields are named with a `table_name.` prefix.

**Edit 2:**

Even `select` will work in place of pluck, the difference is that while `select` returns an array of ActiveRecord objects, pluck returns an array of fields.

Comment: also need to get data from analytics table.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: AnalyticsPage.joins(:users).pluck(:user_field_1, :analytics_pages_field_1). It seems to work. But I am really disappointed that why select is not working previously I worked so many times.

Comment: Actually even select works fine. The only difference is that the 'select' will give you an array of ActiveRecord objects, while pluck will directly give you array.